# Using nested arrays to show and count number of prime factors or other operations

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an algorithm which counts prime factors of a given range of numbers.
For example between 10 and 20.

Result is: number 10: factors are: 2, 5. number 11: factors are: 11. number 12: factors are: 2, 6. etc. ... .

But **I would like to check which numbers have only 2 or 3 or 4 or more prime factors.**

Those numbers I store in an array. And my idea is to assign those individual prime factors to a given number. So I should have an arraylist probably, which is changing dynamically (as name as size also).

For example:

> ArrayOfNumbers[0] = 10;
>   ArrayOfPrimeFactorsOf**10**Number[0] = 2;
>   ArrayOfPrimeFactorsOf**10**Number[1] = 5;
>
> ArrayOfNumbers[1] = 11; ArrayOfPrimeFactorsOf**11**Number[0] = 11;

And I could compare which number has for example 2 or 3 prime factors => by getting size of array of prime factors (ArrayOfPrimeFactorsOf..Number) which belongs to a number of array (ArrayOfNumbers) and display this number and its prime factors also.

My question is: How could I make this as nested array (ArrayOfPrimeFactorsOf..Number) and assign this to ArrayOfNumbers[..]?

Maybe do you have any other idea how to resolve this challenge?

**Below is a program:**

```
 public static void countPrimeFactors() {

    int min = 10; // min number in array
    int max = 20; // max number in array

    Integer[] arrayOfNumbers = new Integer[100000];

    for (int a = 0; a < arrayOfNumbers.length; a++) {

        for (int k = min; k <= max; k++) {

            arrayOfNumbers[a] = k;
            System.out.print(arrayOfNumbers[a] + ": ");

            if (arrayOfNumbers[a] % 2 == 0) {

                System.out.print(2 + " ");
                arrayOfNumbers[a] /= 2;

            }
        // n must be odd at this point. So we can
        // skip one element (i = i +2)
            // i is a current factor
            // array[a] is a current number

        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(arrayOfNumbers[a]); i += 2) {
            // While i divides n, print i and divide n
            if (arrayOfNumbers[a] % i == 0) {

                System.out.print(i + " ");
                arrayOfNumbers[a] /= i;
            }

        }

        // This condition is to handle the case when
        // n is a prime number greater than 2
        if (arrayOfNumbers[a] > 2)

            System.out.print(arrayOfNumbers[a] + " , ");

        }  
        break;
    }

    System.out.print("Length of array[a]: " + arrayOfNumbers.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using maps would be best solution for this, TreeMap especially, key should be number for which you are finding factors, and value should be some other collection containing all factros. Example:

```
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> numbers = new TreeMap<>();
            int min = 10;
    int max = 20;
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> numbers = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        Set<Integer> factors = new TreeSet<>();
        for (int j = 2; j <= i/2; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                factors.add(j);
            }
        }
        //factors.add(i);
        numbers.put(i, factors);

    }
    System.out.println(numbers.get(11).size());
    System.out.println(numbers.values());
```

This is general idea, you could easily get then number of factors for each number by `numbers.get(someNumber).size();`

If you uncomment `factors.add(i);` then number for which we are finding factors would be counted as well, if you need it that way.

**Iterating**

```
  // Iterator mapIt = numbers.keySet().iterator(); - you can only iterate thru map by using iterator

    for(int i = min; i <= max; i++){
        Iterator it = numbers.get(i).iterator();
        System.out.print("Iterating for number " + i+": ");
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.print(it.next()+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This should give you general idea, if you don't like using iterators then use `ArrayList` instead of Set, like `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`

Comment: Thank you for your response. It shows me all possible factors in array of specific number. But how could I iterate by those factors in Map? For example: number 12: [2, 3, 4, 6, 12]. And I would like to iterate in this Map to check if there are 2 factors which can create this number (12).

Comment: You are getting elements of Map by value, so numbers.get(someNumber) will give you Set which contains factors of that number, you iterate through set using iterator, if you are not familiar with it then it might be easier to use an `array` or `ArrayList`, will add code in few minutes.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me more :)